# Is inverse of partial derivative of 2D function equals to its reciprocal

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I saw a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884552/is-a-reciprocal-partial-derivative-equal-to-the-reciprocal-of-the-partial-deriva), but there is still something I don't understand:

suppose I have $f = f(x,y,h(x,y))$ then by chain rule $\frac {\partial f}{\partial h}= \frac {\partial f}{\partial x}\frac {\partial x}{\partial h}+\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}\frac {\partial y}{\partial h}$

and if I understand correctly, this equlas to $\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}(\frac {\partial h}{\partial x})^{-1}+\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}(\frac {\partial y}{\partial h})^{-1}$.

But what shall I do if $\frac {\partial x}{\partial h}=0$ or   $\frac {\partial y}{\partial h}=0$

Comment: None of your formulas make much sense to me... The first one would be fine if you had something like $f(x(h,k),y(h,k))$, but not with $f(x,y,h(x,y))$.

Comment: @HansLundmark then what is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial h}$ in this case?

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what one would even **mean** by $\partial f/\partial h$ in this case! Could you please clarify what you are actually trying to do with this computation? As it stands, I don't think it's possible to answer your question.

Comment: @HansLundmark for example $f(x,y,h)=x^2-2y+3h^2$ where $h(x,y)=x-y^2$ , what is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial h}$?
 isn't it $\frac {\partial f}{\partial h}= \frac {\partial f}{\partial x}\frac {\partial x}{\partial h}+\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}\frac {\partial y}{\partial h}$

Comment: If $f(x,y,h)=x^2-2y+3h^2$, where $x$, $y$ and $h$ are independent variables, then $\partial f/\partial h = 0+0+6h$ (of course). But if you start talking about $h(x,y)=x-y^2$, then the question doesn't make sense anymore! What would it mean to take the partial derivative with respect to a *function*? Or do you want to differentiate the expression $g(x,y) = f(x,y,h(x,y))=x^2-2y+3(x-y^2)^2$? But that's a function of $x$ and $y$ only, not of $h$!

Comment: @HansLundmark $h$ is obviously not independent variable. Can't I write $f=f(x,y,x-y^2)$ and derive it with respect to $x-y^2$?

Comment: What would that *mean*? If you can't explain precisely *what* you want to do, it's meaningless to ask *how* to do it.